# How to fill a range of all values between Min and Max in SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, collections, plsql

I have the following view:

```
select v.* from myview v;

PeriodID | StartMonth | EndMonth
102      |          1 |        4
103      |          3 |        7
104      |          4 |        11
```

And I need to mix this view with this query (another view).

```
select q.* from query q;

Somevalue| AnotherValue| PeriodId
   'abc' |         546 |      102
   'xyz' |         147 |      103
   'bnm' |         652 |      104
```

**I need:**

```
Somevalue| AnotherValue| PeriodId | Month
   'abc' |         546 |      102 |     1
   'abc' |         546 |      102 |     2
   'abc' |         546 |      102 |     3
   'abc' |         546 |      102 |     4
   'xyz' |         147 |      103 |     3
   'xyz' |         147 |      103 |     4
   'xyz' |         147 |      103 |     5
   'xyz' |         147 |      103 |     6
   'xyz' |         147 |      103 |     7
```

If I can get a collection from `startmonth to endmonth` and join it with q, maybe I  could get what I need.

**from:**

```
PeriodID | StartMonth | EndMonth
102      |          1 |        4
103      |          3 |        7
104      |          4 |        11
```

**to:**

```
PeriodID |      Month
102      |          1
102      |          2
102      |          3
102      |          4
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed names to make query clearer

`myview  -->  periods_table`

`query   -->  values_table`

```
SELECT vl.*
      ,pr.month
  FROM (SELECT periodid AS periodid 
              ,LEVEL    AS month
          FROM periods_table t
         WHERE LEVEL >= t.startmonth
         GROUP BY periodid, LEVEL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.endmonth) pr
      , values_table vl
 WHERE pr.periodid = vl.periodid
 ORDER BY pr.periodid, pr.month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as (select 1 monthid from dual union all select 2 from dual
           ...)
select q.somevalue, q.anothervalue, m.periodid, t.monthid
from t 
join myview m on t.monthid between m.startmonth and m.endmonth
join q on q.periodid = m.periodid
```

You can construct a months table with numbers and `join` it to your table.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions to give the same result:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3521/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE myview ( PeriodID, StartMonth, EndMonth ) AS
          SELECT 102, 1, 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 103, 3, 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 104, 4, 11 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE query ( Somevalue, AnotherValue, PeriodId ) AS
          SELECT 'abc', 546, 102 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'xyz', 147, 103 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'bnm', 652, 104 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1 - Using Recursive Subquery Factoring**:

```
WITH Periods ( PeriodID, Month, EndMonth ) AS (
  SELECT PeriodID, StartMonth, EndMonth
  FROM   myview
  WHERE  StartMonth <= EndMonth
  UNION ALL
  SELECT PeriodID, Month + 1, EndMonth
  FROM   Periods
  WHERE  Month < EndMonth
)
SELECT p.PeriodID,
       q.SomeValue,
       q.AnotherValue,
       p.Month
FROM   Periods p
       INNER JOIN
       Query q
       ON ( p.PeriodID = q.PeriodID )
ORDER BY PeriodID, Month
```

**Query 2 - Using a Hierarchical Query**:

```
WITH Periods ( PeriodID, Month ) AS (
  SELECT m.PeriodID,
         t.COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM   myview m,
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT m.StartMonth + LEVEL - 1
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY m.StartMonth + LEVEL - 1 <= m.EndMonth
             )
             AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
           )
         ) t
)
SELECT p.PeriodID,
       q.SomeValue,
       q.AnotherValue,
       p.Month
FROM   Periods p
       INNER JOIN
       Query q
       ON ( p.PeriodID = q.PeriodID )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3521/8/1)**:

```
| PERIODID | SOMEVALUE | ANOTHERVALUE | MONTH |
|----------|-----------|--------------|-------|
|      102 |       abc |          546 |     1 |
|      102 |       abc |          546 |     2 |
|      102 |       abc |          546 |     3 |
|      102 |       abc |          546 |     4 |
|      103 |       xyz |          147 |     3 |
|      103 |       xyz |          147 |     4 |
|      103 |       xyz |          147 |     5 |
|      103 |       xyz |          147 |     6 |
|      103 |       xyz |          147 |     7 |
|      104 |       bnm |          652 |     4 |
|      104 |       bnm |          652 |     5 |
|      104 |       bnm |          652 |     6 |
|      104 |       bnm |          652 |     7 |
|      104 |       bnm |          652 |     8 |
|      104 |       bnm |          652 |     9 |
|      104 |       bnm |          652 |    10 |
|      104 |       bnm |          652 |    11 |
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is the answer of your question.

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE
(
  PERIODID INT,
  STARTMONTH INT,
  ENDMONTH INT
)

DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE
(
  SOMEVALUE VARCHAR(20),
  ANOTHERVALUE INT,
  PERIODID INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE1 VALUES (102,1,3)
INSERT INTO @TABLE1 VALUES (103,3,7)
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 VALUES ('ABC',123,102)
INSERT INTO @TABLE2 VALUES ('BCD',234,103)

;WITH cte
 AS (SELECT PERIODID, STARTMONTH [MONTH],ENDMONTH
     FROM   @TABLE1 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT PERIODID, [MONTH] + 1,ENDMONTH
     FROM   cte
     WHERE  [MONTH] < ENDMONTH)

SELECT T2.SOMEVALUE,T2.ANOTHERVALUE, CTE.PERIODID,CTE.[MONTH] FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN @TABLE2 T2 ON CTE.PERIODID =  T2.PERIODID
ORDER BY CTE.PERIODID,CTE.MONTH
```

Check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c6f0/1) out and try to fit according to your scenario. It will surely works.

Happy Coding

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle and this is invalid SQL for Oracle. It looks like an answer for SQL Server.

Comment: Here tag is attached for sql and in question I don't see any word related to Oracle. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Even if it was _only_ tagged `sql` your answer would be "wrong". The tag `sql` stands for the *query language* SQL, **not** for a specific DBMS product. Your code is not ANSI SQL. Questions for SQL Server will be tagged with `sql-server`. The question was tagged `oracle` right from the start (even with `plsql` and not `t-sql`)